# Limit user access MVC

Tags: php

This is more a theoretical question as to the best practice to only allow users to access certain controller actions within an MVC application.

I've got 2 types of users, "System Users" & "Remote Users". Each should **only** have access to their own set of pages.

This is an inherited framework from a previous developer and the routes are automatically generated so there are no definitions set.

I've thought about creating a whitelist-type access instead of going the full ACL access method. Should I do it pre-router or per method?

Again, I've never had to do this before so what I've thought of doing is something like:

```
$system_users = [
    '/path/to/page',
    '/path/to/page2',
    '/path/to/page3',
    '/path/to/page4',
    //....etc
];

$remote_users = [
    '/remote/page',
    '/remote/page2',
    //....etc
];
```

Then running a custom check before the `Router` (*only if the user(s) are logged in*), like:

```
$user_type = '';
if(Session::get('remote.id') !== FALSE){
    $user_type = 'remote';
} else if(Session::get('system.id') !== FALSE) {
    $user_type = 'system';
}

// now run list
if(!empty($user_type)) {
    if(!in_array(REQUESTED_ROUTE, ${$user_type.'_users'})){
        // Access Denied
        redirect('/NOT_ALLOWED');
    }
    // otherwise carry on with routing.

}
```

<sup>*The above is pseudo code.*</sup>

What would be the best way to go about achieving this? Running it in a session? Pre Router? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In terms of MVC, there's no such term as "certain page". Did you mean controller actions? Anyway, when defining a route map, you can add a key that indicates either a name or a role, which is white-listed.

Comment: @Yang Yeah that's what I meant, updated question haha. This isn't my MVC, it automatically maps routes, not needing them to be defined, hence the thought to handle pre-router.

Comment: If the routing is automatic, then you need to implement a handler that gets executed before controller action is executed. That handler should return an array with roles and their associated allowed controller actions. For example, one rule might look so: `return ['remote' => ['indexAction', 'viewAction']]`, which means that users that have 'remote' role, are allowed to execute index and view actions, otherwise an error should be thrown in some way.

Comment: Did you use any MVC framework? As the MVC request lifecycle, after the framework detect environment, config and load service providers, Route will be called to resolved this request. Some frameworks support FILTER component to be handle before or after Route execute. Your code handle limiting user business at Pre-route (before route) and i think it gonna be OK. But in some frameworks ex. Laravel, Yii, Cake, i could handle at Filter component for shiny and clear. Refer: https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/lifecycle

Comment: @Yang Would I be best to just go with a filter for one user group (*remote*) as they only require access to a limited number of pages? And match against that pre-controller/action? If you want to throw that up as an answer, I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a database table with Groups and Permissions to them(ACL Component/Controller).
Then, You need to assign one(or none) allowed pages into table.

After user tried to go to other page - You need to check page address(or check Controller+Action he try to perform) and to give info or error message.

You should have 3 tables:

- Groups
- Permissions
- Actions

In actions you need to create next columns:

- ID
  V.1
- Controller
- Action

V.2
 - Page

In Permissions:

- ID
- Group_id
- Permisssion_id
- Access

Groups table:

- ID
- Group name

When You adding some new actions, You need to add it to all Groups with 'Not allowed' permission (Set access to 0). And when You deleting some action - You need to delete all actions in Permissions table with foreign key.

Comment: I didn't want to go down the full ACL path as it's only a few custom pages that require the locked down access.